# JavaScript compare two JSON files and outputting new objects only

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, compare, diff

I want to compare two JSON files and output only the newly added objects based on their "Id". I also need to ignore changes in the position of the objects within the JSON file (I don't want to compare line changes).

You'll notice in the code below that Greg's age has changed - I don't want to include these sort of (Key:Value) changes in my output either.

I'm currently using a package called json-diff.

Here's my current code:

```
const jsonDiff = require('json-diff');

var oldJson = {
    "data": [ 
      {
        "Id": "2",
        "Name": "Greg",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "age": "70"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Tom",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "age": "10"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
};

var newJson = {
    "data": [
      {
        "Id": "2",
        "Name": "Greg",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "age": "20" // Even though Greg's age has changed, I don't want it in my output
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "3",
        "Name": "Bob",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "age": "30"
          }
        ]
      },  
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Tom",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "age": "10"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
};

function compare(newJson, oldJson) {
    let rawDiff = jsonDiff.diff(newJson.data, oldJson.data);
    let prettyDiff = JSON.stringify(rawDiff).replace(/,\[" "]/g, '');
    console.log(prettyDiff);
}

compare(newJson, oldJson);
```

Current output:

```
[
  [
    "~",
    {
      "ranges": [
        [
          "-",
          {
            "age": "20"
          }
        ],
        [
          "+",
          {
            "age": "70"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    "-",
    {
      "Id": "3",
      "Name": "Bob",
      "ranges": [
        {
          "age": "30"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Required output:

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "Id": "3",
        "Name": "Bob",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "age": "30"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can just iterate through the array and find new ids alone. This problem is not a generic one, and you need to build a custom logic. No package or library will do the exact thing you are expecting

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add the code you have tried and explain what you have problem with.

Comment: @Molda updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not sure if this is your need but

```js
var oldJson = {
    "data": [ 
      { "Id": "2", "Name": "Greg", "ranges": [ { "age": "70" } ] },
      { "Id": "1", "Name": "Tom", "ranges": [ { "age": "10" } ] }
    ]
};

var newJson = {
    "data": [
        { "Id": "2", "Name": "Greg", "ranges": [ { "age": "20" } ] },
        { "Id": "3", "Name": "Bob", "ranges": [ { "age": "30" } ] },  
        { "Id": "1", "Name": "Tom", "ranges": [ { "age": "10" } ] }
    ]
};

function compare(newJson, oldJson) {
    // get Id's from oldJson
    let ids = oldJson.data.map(ch => ch.Id);
    // filter from newJson that's not inside from old ids
    return newJson.data.filter(ch => !ids.includes(ch.Id));
}

console.log(compare(newJson, oldJson)); // [ { Id: '3', Name: 'Bob', ranges: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and so simple! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to solve a more complex problem:

```
    function compareJsonArrays(currentArray, newArray) {
        const diff = {
            newItems: [],
            deletedItems: [],
            updatedItems: []
        };

        const currentSet = new Set(currentArray.map(item => item.id));
        const newSet = new Set(newArray.map(item => item.id));

        for (const element of newArray) {
            if (!currentSet.has(element.id)) {
                diff.newItems.push(element);
            } else {
                const currentItemIndex = currentArray.findIndex(item => item.id === element.id);
                if (!compareObjects(element, currentArray[currentItemIndex])) {
                    diff.updatedItems.push(element);
                }
            }
        }

        for (const element of currentArray) {
            if (!newSet.has(element.id)) {
                diff.deletedItems.push(element);
            }
        }

        return diff;
    }

    function compareObjects(obj1, obj2) {
        return JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2);
    }
```

Comment: This answer could benefit from example, particularly via a [StackSnippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).